# How can I play DRM-protected DVDs in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, dvd

I'm having problems playing DVDs in Ubuntu Jaunty (9.04); some DVDs work, but most don't. The error message in dmesg is:

```
end_request: I/O error, dev sr0
```

All DVD player programs simply freeze after this error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is css encrypted disks that causes this error. The solution is to install 
libdvdcss2, which can be install by first installing libdvdread4, and then running

```
/usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

This will add the medibuntu-repos and install libdvdcss2 and solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed my problem. Unfortunately a little late; I already bought a brand new DVD drive and SATA cables only to discover I still couldn't play DVDs. Thank you very much to the media industry, making just a bit more profit thanks to ridiculous DRM!

Answer (score 3):

The [Medibuntu](http://www.medibuntu.org/) repository has the packages for supporting encrypted DVD playback. Check out [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Medibuntu#Playing%20Encrypted%20DVDs) on the Ubuntu Wiki for installation details.